# How can grouped the TEXT/ELEMENT by xsl:for-each-group element in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

**INPUT XML:**

```
<overline-start id="tie1" specific-use="tie-bar"/>PtCl<sub>2</sub>(P((CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub><italic toggle="yes">n</italic></sub>)<sub>3</sub><overline-end rid="tie1"/>
```

**EXPECTED XML:**

```
<overline id="tie1" specific-use="tie-bar">PtCl<sub>2</sub>(P((CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub><italic toggle="yes">n</italic></sub>)<sub>3</sub></overline>
```

**MY XSLT 2.0 Code:**

```
<xsl:template match="overline-start">
<xsl:for-each-group select="self::overline-start" group-adjacent="self::overline-start[following-sibling::overline-end]">
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
<overline>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
</overline>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Isn't there any parent container element for the `overline-start` and `overline-end` elements? It seems you should match on that parent container element and then it becomes a classic, text book use of `xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="overline-start"` together with a nested `xsl:for-each-group group-ending-with="overline-end"`. Not sure whether you also need to compare the `id` and `tid` attributes.

Comment: Currently its coming under the 'p' element but it may other parent element, Yes we comparing the id and rid

Comment: I think the simple example is not sufficient to explain your requirements. Can the there be various `overline-start` elements in a common parent? Can there be non-matching `overline-start/end` elements (e.g. `<overline-start id="o1"/><foo/>...<bar/></overline-end rid="o2"/>`)? What would happen in that case?

Comment: But here select attribute is required if we are using nested xsl:for-each-group group-ending-with="overline-end"

Comment: for now its coming under the p element at all

Comment: Yes, sure, the `select` inside the nested is required, it will be `current-group()` or `current-group() except .`, you might need a check inside the outer for-each-group, as it is usually the case with the `group-starting-with`, as XSLT also forms a group for non-matching items. As I said, the exact code depends on how variable your input is but if you need to use `for-each-group` then for the given structure `group-starting-with`/`group-ending-with` seems more adequate than `group-adjacent`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the requirement in comments, I tried it *@Martin Honnen* 's way:

Assuming input as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
      <overline-start id="tie1" specific-use="tie-bar"/>PtCl<sub>2</sub>(P((CH<sub>2</sub>)<sub><italic toggle="yes">n</italic></sub>)<sub>3</sub><overline-end rid="tie1"/>
</p>
```

A **2.0** solution can be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <overline>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="* | text()" group-starting-with="overline-start">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="overline-end">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                <xsl:sequence select="(current-group() except .) [position() != last()]" />
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </overline>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZW8/1

Comment: I would think the construction of the `overline` result element belongs into the nested `for-each-group` where you have established a group and want to wrap it into an `overline` element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen : But wouldn't it be creating multiple `<overline>` including starting and ending elements ?

Comment: I suspect the task in general is to identify the nodes between pairs of `overline-start`/`overline-end` and wrap them into `overline` elements. All hard to tell with that simple example where there is only that single sequence.

Comment: @Javed : Actually there are multiples instances (i.e. See Input example) are coming in the single 'p' element,  is it possible to group of each instance under the overline' element. we are matching the template 'overline-start' here.

Comment: @Javed : Thanks Vebbie, but its not working properly, is it possible to matching the template 'overline-start'

Comment: @Javed : For each instance should be like as given expected output example (i.e. Output example)